# Все ли браузеры поддерживают zoom CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, кроссбраузерность, zoom, crossbrowsertesting

Всем привет. Как вы знаете экранов много и многие отличаются соотношением сторон и разрешением экрана. Я хочу написать код для масштабирования экрана с помощью css, свойства «zoom», для разных основных и промежуточных разрешений экранов.
И задался вопросом для себя, все ли браузеры поддерживают CSS zoom? Если не все, я имею в вижу современные версии браузеров, то какие есть аналоги для кроссбраузерности?

В интернете я нашел такой код:

```
zoom: 2; /* IE */
-moz-transform: scale(2); /* Firefox */
-moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
-o-transform: scale(2); /* Opera */
-o-transform-origin: 0 0;
-webkit-transform: scale(2); /* Safari And Chrome */
-webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
transform: scale(2); /* Standard Property */
transform-origin: 0 0;  /* Standard Property */
```

Но, код кривой, например если у вас адаптивная оболочка сайта, то zoom и transform: scale() - несовместимы.

Кто что скажет ребята?

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=zoom

Comment: @Дмытрык Судя по данным, нужна заплатка для Лисы. -moz-transform: scale(2); /* Firefox */
-moz-transform-origin: 0 0;

Comment: zoom — нестандартное свойство, и лучше бы его вообще не использовать

Comment: @andreymal Смотря где и как его использовать. Прекрасно работает на Хроме, Опера. Я хочу сделать идеальную адаптивную оболочку, и, вместо того, чтобы не работать над каждым элементом для промежуточных разрешений экрана, масштабирование прекрасное решение, главное его верно рассчитать. Благо, калькулятором многие умеют пользоваться.

Comment: @VladimirRodichev в любой момент может перестать работать, потому что оно нестандартное — стоит гуглу только захотеть.

Comment: @andreymal много лет как работает. Так если думать стоит кому-то захотеть, то любое свойство могут переписать или убрать. Мне нужны альтернативные решения. Я тестировал несколько вариантов, разных и могу с уверенностью сказать, -webkit-transform: scale - хуже, чем zoom.

Comment: @VladimirRodichev так-то вероятность убирания стандартных свойств намного меньше чем нестандартных

Comment: @andreymal zoom оставят.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По поводу поддержки различными браузерами свойств CSS - все это можно посмотреть на сайте  https://caniuse.com/#search=zoom
https://caniuse.com/#search=transform

Comment: Спасибо, уже знаю. И мы, с пользователями создали несколько интересных решений, пару вариантов такие, чтобы все браузеры восприняли код как надо.

Answer (score 1):

Поддержка браузерами [zoom](http://htmlbook.ru/css/zoom)....
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это старые данные. у меня Opera к примеру прекрасно поддерживает CSS zoom.

Comment: @VladimirRodichev добавил

Comment: Спасибо. Данные за какой год?

Comment: @VladimirRodichev думаю актуальнее не найдете [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/@viewport/zoom)

Answer (score 0):

Не все браузеры поддерживают zoom.
В частности это касается Лисицы.
Но, есть решение. Публикую:

```
@media (max-width: 1680px) and (min-width: 1601px) {
    html {
        zoom: 87.5%;
    }
    @-moz-document url-prefix() {
        html {
            transform: scale(0.875);
            transform-origin: left top;
            width: calc(100% / 0.875);
            height: calc(100% / 0.875);
        }
    }
}
```

Детальнее тут:
[Кроссбраузерный zoom?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/956226/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-zoom/956387#956387)