# Кроссбраузерный zoom?

Tags: css, кроссбраузерность, transform, zoom

Почему к примеру на Firefox не работает zoom, и работает moz-transform: scale - криво? Zoom масштабирует целиком, если использовать в html, body, на весь экран...
transform: scale - если уменьшаем, то уменьшает и оставляет черные полосы по бокам и сверху, как-бы экран в экране получается. Есть альтернатива зуму для Лисы?

**Пример: Браузер Лиса со scale:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Пример: Браузер Хром с zomm:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видите разницу?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91034/discussion-on-question-by-vladimir-rodichev--zoom).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот рабочее решение:

```
@media (max-width: 1680px) and (min-width: 1601px) {
 html {
    zoom: 87.5%;
 }
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
 html {
    transform: scale(0.875);
    transform-origin: left top;
    width: calc(100% / 0.875);
    height: calc(100% / 0.875);
    }
  }
}
```

На всякий случай немного объясню:

```
@media (max-width: 1680px) and (min-width: 1601px)
```

Промежуток в котором будет работать код исходя из ширины экрана.

Zoom - для современных браузеров, оставляем, ниже прописываем конкретно для Мозилы/Огненной Лисы (только они воспримут код):

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {....}
```

У меня работает.

Comment: @andreymal Вот вам моё решение, основанное на вашем с калком. К высоте я тоже применил Калк.

Comment: Уведомления пользователей через @ всё равно не работают, если под текущим ответом пользователи не написали ни одного комментария

Comment: @andreymal Теперь буду знать. Спасибо.

Comment: В ответе код обрезанный

Comment: @Дмытрык в каком плане обрезанный?

Comment: @Дмытрык Код не обрезанный. Если ты пишешь тут, то старайся выражаться конкретнее. В верхней части код полный, в качестве примера для определенной ширины окна. Это CSS. Если тебе он нужен, то можно двумя путями написать: 1) напрямую в документе, обернуть в тэги <style></style>; 2) Прописать во внешнем файле nazvanie.css

Comment: @andreymal, все - понял )

Comment: @VladimirRodichev, расслабьтесь

Comment: @Дмытрык не напрягались. не война. стараемся обменяться опытом, поделиться знаниями, интересными решениями.

Answer (score 2):

Приниципиальное отличие `transform` от `zoom` в том, что `zoom` меняет реальный размер элемента, и это сказывается на положении соседних элементов и на всём размере страницы. `transform` же — чисто декоративная штука, она визуально меняет элемент, но в плане расчёта геометрии размеры элемента остаются стандартными и никак не влияют на основную страницу. В примере ниже можно наглядно увидеть разницу между `transform: scale` и `zoom` (запускать нужно в браузере Chrome, так как Firefox на момент написания данного ответа не поддерживает `zoom`):

```css
.ramka {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 20px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.demo-transform {
  transform: scale(1.4);
  transform-origin: left top;
}

.demo-zoom {
  zoom: 1.4;
}

.img {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="ramka">
 transform: scale(1.4)<br/>
 <div class="demo-transform">
   <img class="img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyEgY.png" alt="" width="100" height="100" />
 </div>
</div>

<div class="ramka">
 zoom: 1.4<br/>
 <div class="demo-zoom">
   <img class="img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyEgY.png" alt="" width="100" height="100" />
 </div>
</div>
```

Так как transform использует исходные размеры элемента и просто масштабирует изображение, то при применении ко всей странице ширина не пересчитывается, и, как вы показали в своём скриншоте, [по краям образуется пустота](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5U3H.png).

Уменьшившуюся ширину можно исправить с помощью `transform-origin: left top` и `width: calc(1 / 0.6)` (где `0.6` это величина scale), однако это не решит проблемы с высотой, потому что она, в отличие от ширины, заранее не известна. При scale<1 [снизу будет пустота](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhNXF.png), а при scale>1 низ страницы наоборот обрежется. А всё потому что transform не меняет геометрию.

К сожалению, стандартного кроссбраузерного аналога `zoom` я не знаю (есть какой-то [@viewport zoom](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/@viewport), но с его поддержкой всё ещё хуже, и заставить его работать я не смог).

Один из вариантов, как с этим жить, [вы описали сами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/956226/%d0%9a%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-zoom/956437#956437): использовать `transform` для Firefox и `zoom` для остальных браузеров. Судя по тому, как сильно вы «любите» Лису, этот вариант вас вполне устроит :) Но о том, что `zoom` нестандартный и может быть в любой момент удалён из браузеров, я вас уже предупреждал. (Хотя было бы прекрасно, если бы его стандартизировали и реализовали в Firefox, но это дело далёкого будущего.)

Но можно в принципе пересчитывать всю геометрию самостоятельно с помощью JavaScript. Ниже я написал функцию, которая пересчитывает `height` для всех элементов с классом `js-zoomed` (при этом `width` прописывается в CSS). Вы можете добавить класс `js-zoomed` к элементу `<html>` на своём сайте, чтобы пересчитывать размеры всего сайта.

Проблемное ограничение данного способа в том, что этот скрипт нужно перезапускать при КАЖДОМ изменении размеров элементов. В примере я повесил перезапуск на браузерное событие `resize` (оно приводит к изменению размеров почти всегда), но если вы динамически меняете какие-то элементы какими-то скриптами, то вам надо перезапускать это вручную в коде.

Ну а ещё это просто дикий костыль с кучей ограничений. Например, у увеличеннного элемента есть торчащая вниз невидимая пустота (она образуется из-за того, `height` и `transform` действуют вместе), и эта пустота добавляет ненужную полосу прокрутки, так что пришлось исправить это с помощью `overflow: hidden`.

```js
function recalcZoomedElements() {
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('js-zoomed');
  
  // Обрабатываем элементы в обратном порядке, чтобы
  // не было проблем с вложенными друг в друга элементами
  for (var i = elems.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var elem = elems[i];
    
    // Убираем старый расчёт height
    elem.style.height = '';
    
    // Браузер посчитает высоту автоматически с учётом transform;
    // забираем её значение себе
    var rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    var newHeight = rect.height;
    
    // Ставим посчитанную браузером высоту, изменяя геомертию
    elem.style.height = newHeight + 'px';
  }
}

// Перерасчёт при первой загрузке страницы
recalcZoomedElements();

// Перерасчёт при каждом изменении размера окна браузера
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {recalcZoomedElements()});
```

```css
.ramka {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 10px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;

  /* Вот так имитируем окно браузера для данного примера: */
  /* его ширина заране известна и за пределы окна ничего не вылезает */
  width: 140px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.demo-transform {
  transform: scale(1.4);
  width: calc(100% / 1.4);
  transform-origin: left top;
}

.demo-zoom {
  zoom: 1.4;
}

.img {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="ramka">
 transform: scale(1.4) no js<br/>
 <div class="demo-transform">
   <img class="img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyEgY.png" alt="" width="100" height="100" />
 </div>
</div>

<div class="ramka">
 transform: scale(1.4) with js<br/>
 <div class="demo-transform js-zoomed">
   <img class="img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyEgY.png" alt="" width="100" height="100" />
 </div>
</div>

<div class="ramka">
 zoom: 1.4<br/>
 <div class="demo-zoom">
   <img class="img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyEgY.png" alt="" width="100" height="100" />
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Лису я не люблю, по факту такой браузер есть, только это. В остальном с методом калк у Лисы пустоты при скайле меньше 1 не наблюдается: http://prntscr.com/mxq88d

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы не использовать `transform: scale()`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.zoom {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.zoom img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.zoom:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(2);
  -moz-transform: scale(2);
  -ms-transform: scale(2);
  -o-transform: scale(2);
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<div class="zoom">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/Firefox_Developer_Edition_logo.png">
</div>
```

Comment: У данного метода есть минус. Возможно он нормальный для элементов. Но, вы попробуйте применить его на всю страницу целиком в разных браузерах. В частности, в Лисе (один из худших браузеров на мой взгляд), на уменьшение масштаба, например 0.81. Возможно, решение есть альтернативное. Если есть, то здорово.

Comment: @VladimirRodichev Лиса отличный браузер. То, что вы хотите применять нестандартные свойства вроде zoom — исключительно ваши личные проблемы :)

Comment: @andreymal лиса жрет ресурсов много и виснет. Отличный браузер (пока что) Опера.

Comment: @VladimirRodichev ваша информация о лисе устарела на пару лет, с версии 57 не жрёт и не виснет. Опера — это просто хром с другим названием.

Comment: @andreymal я только вчера последнюю (вроде как) скачал с оф сайта. и чтобы посмотреть код у разных сайтов, висла. Может быть вы качали с особого ресурса? Дайте ссылку на посл. версию.Может я не там качал.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 основная проблема автора вопроса, которую он явно не озвучил (а возможно, и не осознал ещё), — в том, что ему нужно, чтобы при изменении размера изменялись и реальные геометрические размеры объекта, как при использовании zoom. В вашем примере они не изменяются и элемент вылезает за края страницы. Попробуйте поменять на zoom и запустить в хроме — не только не вылезет за края, но и даже полоса прокрутки появится, именно такое поведение ожидает автор

Comment: @VladimirRodichev https://www.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/

Comment: @andreymal Да, именно так. Я думал меня поняли, но мне нужно было лучше объяснить.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 вот решения. Если вам интересно, вы можете узнать о них. Спасибо за участие.

Answer (score 0):

```
function zoomhtml() {
        var wid = $(window).width(),
            len;
        if (wid < 1600) {
            len = wid / 1600;
            console.log(len)
                // $("html").css("zoom", len);
            $("html").css({
                "-moz-transform": "scale(" + len + ")",
                "width": "calc(100% / " + len + ")",
                "transform": "scale(" + len + ")",
                "transform-origin": "left top"
            }, {
                "-moz-transform-origin": "0 0"
            });
        }
    };
    zoomhtml();
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]